# what FFMPEG performance settings to use for processing videos for the web

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a few questions regarding usage of ffmpeg for processing videos for the web. I'm a beginner so please bear with me (although I read some docs on the internet)

#### Performance

- First of all, given the fact that FFMPEG utilizes all cores at 100%, what is the actual parallelism efficiency?

Let's assume the following scenario. I have a video (fullHD, doesn't matter what encoders / compression format was used to obtain the video) and I want to resize (downscale) to various sizes (e.g. 240px, 480px and 720px height) using mp4 format (thus using libx264 with aac codecs).

Using ffmpeg, I see that all of my laptop's cores (8) are used at 100% and I was wondering what scenarios can improve the overall performance of the whole processing task. So this leads us to basically 2 scenarios: Assuming the video mentioned above as input, for obtaining the 3 output videos (@ 240px, 480px and 720px height sizes), we:

1. Process input video and obtain 1 output video at a time, and let all the cores work at the same time at 100%;
2. Process the video to obtain all output videos in parallel, by bounding each output video to a single processor core which'll work at 100%;

So the question is actually reduced to the parallelism efficiency of the ffmpeg program.

This means that letting ffmpeg process the task `procVideo` - *which takes 1 input video to produce 1 single output video (transcoding/downscaling and so on)* - on N processor cores doesn't mean it finish the task N times faster than letting it run the same task bound to a single core. So if the efficiency is smaller than 100%, it's better to have N `procVideo` tasks in parallel, each bound to a single core, rather than doing the task sequentially for each output video.

---

#### Codecs

Other than the above performance problem, the usage of codecs bugs me. I am trying to obtain mp4 videos because of the wide implementation of the format in html5 browsers.

So having a video as input in any format, I want to convert it to mp4. So I'm using libx264 codec with aac.

- Use libx264, x264 or h264 for video encoding/decoding?
- Use libfdk_aac, libaacplus or aac for audio encoding/decoding to aac?

Also, I would like to know what are the licesing fees for each of the above codec, as the online resources on these are quite limited / hard to understand.

If anyone could shed some light on those questions, I would really be grateful! Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few unrelated questions here.

#### FFmpeg performance

All that follows is based on my personal experience, and is by no means empirical evidence.

Try as you might, you'll be very hard-pressed to find a software that is more optimized than FFmpeg in performance.
Also keep in mind that most of the work in this case will be done by libx264, which is very mature and insanely fast. (Just try to encode an equivalent video to H.265 using ffmpeg and the not-quite-mature-yet x265, and you'll understand what I mean).

So in summary, you can assume that a single encoding is as fast as possible on the machine, and parallelizing will not improve anything.

An alternative solution to test is to ask ffmpeg to encode several files in a single invocation, so that the decoding part of the pipeline is only done once, as explained here: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Creating%20multiple%20outputs.

In the end, you should test each case by carefully measuring the total encoding time for each scenario.

#### Codecs

x264 and libx264 are one and the same, the difference being that the latter is used by ffmpeg instead of being a standalone tool.
By "h264", I'm not sure what you mean. In ffmpeg, h264 is only a decoder, while libx264 is the encoder. You don't have much choice there.

About AAC, all essential information is present in this web page: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/AAC
So if you can obtain a build of ffmpeg linked against libfdk_aac, this is the safest bet for good quality audio.

#### License fees

This is a very sensitive subject. Most people will outright refuse to give you advice, and I'm no exception, because any legal advice implies liability in case of litigation.

To sum things up, see the following urls:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H.264/MPEG-4_AVC#Patent_licensing
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Audio_Coding#Licensing_and_patents

Some might argue that the difficulty of understanding the information is somehow done on purpose in order to confuse the general public.